# How to take multiple inputs from he user using 2D array in JAVA?

Tags: java, input

While completing a problem i got a problem where i am getting run time error whenever user giving more than 3 inputs . Example of 5 inputs line  given bellow

> Input:
>
> 2 5
>
> 5 1
>
> 2 1
>
> 3 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 4 1
>
> In the first line "5" is number of test cases .

### My code only runs for first 3 lines of inputs i hope anyone can help me to identify the problem in my code so that it works for any number of  input line given by the user .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner robo=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=robo.nextInt();
    int array [][]=new int [5][2];

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
        array[i][j]=robo.nextInt();
      }
    }

    int word=num;
    String result="";

    if(array[0][0]>num){
      System.out.print("NO");
    }else{
      for(int i=0;i<num1-1;i++){       
        word=array[i][1]+word;
        if(array[i+1][0]<word){
          result="YES";
        }else{
          result="NO";
        }
      }
      System.out.println(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem:

In this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){

  for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){

    array[i][j]=robo.nextInt();
  }

}
```

`i` runs from 0 to 4 and `j` ALSO runs from 0 to 4, because the length of your array is 5, even if each of the 5 array entries is an array with size 2. Still `array.length` of the "outer" array is 5. And therefore `array[i][j]` will throw an exception as soon as `j` becomes 2 or bigger, because each of the inner arrays has only 2 elements.

Comment: so that means J loop will run upto 2 ?

Comment: Both the loops will run from 0 to the number entered by the user. And as soon as j becomes bigger than 2 you get an Exception.